# Algorithm for placing dashboard panels in unoccupied space

Tags: javascript, algorithm, user-interface, dashboard

I'm working on a portal/dashboard type interface which has panels/widgets that can be freely dragged around the dashboard space as long as they don't overlay any other panels. New panels can be added to the dashboard via a menu containing all available panels, and when a menu item is clicked, the panel is placed into the dashboard. The panels currently occupying the dashboard space are all represented in an object like this:

```
{
    'panel_1': { top: 0, left: 0, width: 300, height: 350 },
    'panel_2': { top: 0, left: 370, width: 200, height: 275 },
    'panel_3': { top: 370, left: 0, width: 275, height: 400 },
    ...
}
```

My question is, what is a valid algorithm that would, when the user clicks one in the menu, correctly place a new panel (of a given width and height) in unoccupied space that is closest to a left and top (x and y) value of 0, 0, without overlapping any of the existing panels?

Comment: This is one step of first fit rectangle packing.

Comment: Have you looked at masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, simple bruteforce algorithm will fit you. As I remember, fit rectangle solve another problem

Iterate over your dashboard axis to find out, whether you can place your rectangle, until `X < rectangle.widh + dashboard.width`, same for Y.

Foreach X,Y on dashboard iterate over every panel to find whether they overlap. You can apply some optimization, to decrease amount of iteration. If panel overlap rectangle, you can increase X or Y(which is in nested loop) not by 1, but by width or height of panel.

In most cases, you will not make `dashboard.width*dashboard.height*panel.count` iteration. With some optimization, it will find best fit rather quick

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if anyone wants a proof of concept then it looks like this:

```
function findSpace(width, height) {
    var $ul = $('.snap-layout>ul');
    var widthOfContainer = $ul.width();
    var heightOfContainer = $ul.height();
    var $lis = $ul.children('.setup-widget'); // The li is on the page and we dont want it to collide with itself

    for (var y = 0; y < heightOfContainer - height + 1; y++) {
        var heightOfShortestInRow = 1;
        for (var x = 0; x < widthOfContainer - width + 1; x++) {
            //console.log(x + '/' + y);
            var pos = { 'left': x, 'top': y };
            var $collider = $(isOverlapping($lis, pos, width, height));
            if ($collider.length == 0) {
                // Found a space
                return pos;
            }

            var colliderPos = $collider.position();
            // We have collided with something, there is no point testing the points within this widget so lets skip them
            var newX = colliderPos.left + $collider.width() - 1; // -1 to account for the ++ in the for loop
            x = newX > x ? newX : x; // Make sure that we are not some how going backwards and looping forever

            var colliderBottom = colliderPos.top + $collider.height();
            if (heightOfShortestInRow == 1 || colliderBottom - y < heightOfShortestInRow) {
                heightOfShortestInRow = colliderBottom - y; // This isn't actually the height its just the distance from y to the bottom of the widget, y is normally at the top of the widget tho
            }
        }
        y += heightOfShortestInRow - 1;
    }

    //TODO: Add the widget to the bottom
}


function isOverlapping($obsticles, tAxis, width, height) {
    var t_x, t_y;
    if (typeof (width) == 'undefined') {
        // Existing element passed in
        var $target = $(tAxis);
        tAxis = $target.position();
        t_x = [tAxis.left, tAxis.left + $target.outerWidth()];
        t_y = [tAxis.top, tAxis.top + $target.outerHeight()];
    } else {
        // Coordinates and dimensions passed in
        t_x = [tAxis.left, tAxis.left + width];
        t_y = [tAxis.top, tAxis.top + height];
    }

    var overlap = false;

    $obsticles.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var thisPos = $this.position();
        var i_x = [thisPos.left, thisPos.left + $this.outerWidth()]
        var i_y = [thisPos.top, thisPos.top + $this.outerHeight()];

        if (t_x[0] < i_x[1] && t_x[1] > i_x[0] &&
             t_y[0] < i_y[1] && t_y[1] > i_y[0]) {
            overlap = this;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return overlap;
}
```